# Normalize multiindex dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to normalize multiindex dataframe: subtract it's mean and divide by its standard deviation. That's how you do it with a normal (not multiindex) dataframe:

```
df4 = (df4-df4.mean(1)) / df.std(1)
```

However, with the multiindex dataframe it does not work: I am getting this absurdish error:

```
ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names
```

So I wonder if there is work-around, simpler than flattening and de-flattening the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `subtract` and `divide` methods so you can specify the appropriate axis of operation:

```
df.subtract(mean, axis=0).divide(std, axis=0)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2016)

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(8,3)), index=arrays)
mean = df.mean(axis=1)
std = df.std(axis=1)
print(df.subtract(mean, axis=0).divide(std, axis=0))
```

yields

```
                0         1         2
bar one -0.377964  1.133893 -0.755929
    two -0.755929  1.133893 -0.377964
baz one  0.000000 -1.000000  1.000000
    two -0.800641  1.120897 -0.320256
foo one -0.164957 -0.907265  1.072222
    two -1.154701  0.577350  0.577350
qux one -0.577350  1.154701 -0.577350
    two -0.377964  1.133893 -0.755929
```